# How to connect to webSocket using Starscream?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to establish a socket connection. i am using below code

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
    request.timeoutInterval = 2.0
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("header", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    socket = WebSocket(request: request)
    socket.delegate = self
    socket.connect()
```

And delegates are

```
func websocketDidConnect(socket: WebSocketClient) {

    print("websocket is connected")
}

func websocketDidDisconnect(socket: WebSocketClient, error: Error?) {

    if let e = error as? WSError {

        print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.message)")

    } else if let e = error {

        print("websocket is disconnected: \(e.localizedDescription)")

    } else {

        print("websocket disconnected")
    }
}

func websocketDidReceiveMessage(socket: WebSocketClient, text: String) {

    print("Received text: \(text)")
}

func websocketDidReceiveData(socket: WebSocketClient, data: Data) {

    print("Received data: \(data.count)")
}
```

i am getting this error

websocket is disconnected: Invalid HTTP upgrade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delegates look ok. The issue happens upon negotiating connection protocol parameters with the websocket server. Instead of crafting `URLRequest` try something like this:

```
 let socket = WebSocket(url: URL(string: "wss://yourWebSocketServer")!)
```

Comment: What if I want to set custom headers? There's no way to set them while using `WebSocket` directly.

Comment: You can set headers by altering the request. Just check here: https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream#custom-headers