# How to use url starting with "HTTPS" protocol as WebSocket url in Starscream?

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, wss, starscream

I'm using Starscream Web Socket library. To create web socket I have url starting with HTTPS. But Starscream uses "ws & wss" protocols for sockets. How do I resolve this issue?
Mostly socket url starts with **ws** or **wss**. But URL I have is looks like

> https://example.com:8034/socket.io/socket.io.js

I want to set this url as Socket url. But don't know how?

Comment: see this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48353856/how-to-connect-to-websocket-using-starscream

Comment: @DipakiOS please share more about your question. What have you tried before? And maybe you want to check this out -> https://developerinsider.co/difference-between-http-and-http-2-0-websocket/